# Outlook add on sideloading fails because of unauthorized access

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

As title indicates, my add on is failing to sideload. I am trying to follow the official tutorial of microsoft on how to build your first outlook, developing a taskpane: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

I followed this tutorial down to the last letter but I am getting the same error. Basically after I set up my project, and I chose the language and name for my add on, I run the npm start from my vs code terminal, then I am being prompted to microsoft login portal, I sign up and then back to my vs code terminal I get 401..

I have my microsoft exchange account connected to outlook and it works, so I know thats not the issue..if anyone could help me I would appreciate it!

**Here is the error:**

Successfully registered package! (??)
STDERR: (×) Error: [Login] Failed to retrieve token silently. If you encounter this problem multiple times, you can delete `C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\.fx\account` and try again. invalid_scope: 70011 - [2024-02-19 08:17:50Z]: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/AppDefinitions.ReadWrite openid profile offline_access' does not exist. Trace ID: fbf8f4fb-e2bb-4a2c-83d8-07c3ec040800 Correlation ID: d3d06969-78ae-4ba1-be44-85e4c4b3239c Timestamp: 2024-02-19 08:17:50Z - Correlation ID: d3d06969-78ae-4ba1-be44-85e4c4b3239c - Trace ID: fbf8f4fb-e2bb-4a2c-83d8-07c3ec040800
(×) Error: Sideloading failed.
(×) Error: {"statusCode":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}
(×) Error: m365.UnhandledError: An unexpected error has occurred while performing the M365 task. {"stack":"Error: {"message":"Request failed with status code 401","detail":"{\"statusCode\":401,\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}","tracingId":""}\n    at createError (C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\Desktop\Plugin\SheildIT\node_modules\@microsoft\teamsfx-cli\lib\index.js:14:300960)\n    at settle (C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\Desktop\Plugin\SheildIT\node_modules\@microsoft\teamsfx-cli\lib\index.js:14:305240)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\Desktop\Plugin\SheildIT\node_modules\@microsoft\teamsfx-cli\lib\index.js:14:290544)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)","message":"{"message":"Request failed with status code 401","detail":"{\"statusCode\":401,\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}","tracingId":""}","config":{}}

Comment: Do you get any errors when you sideload add-ins manually?

Comment: For some reason I can't sideload manually, I tried following the tutorial on that but I just dont see that window which they have in picture of tutorial, here is tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing?tabs=windows
Instead when I click get add ins I get redirected to microsoft store where I can browse and add addins..

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that you are not authorized in Office 365 to sideload the add-in:

> Error: Sideloading failed. (×) Error: {"statusCode":401,"message":"Unauthorized"} (×) Error: m365.UnhandledError: An unexpected error has occurred while performing the M365 task.

You may try to sideload the add-in manually, see [Manually sideload an add-in to Office on the web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing#manually-sideload-an-add-in-to-office-on-the-web) for more information.

Comment: So the thing I am confused at is the fact that I am authorized..like when I get prompted to sign in after I do npm start the window says you are now authenticated and may close this window, but then back in my terminal I get that error..and for the life of me I cant figure out why, could there be perhaps a some kind of restriction on outlook account or something?
I also noticed that in my cache from .fx folder the json file which contains token i empty, could it be thats what causing this? Also link that you provided is not for outlook :/